# python for loop through multiple arrays then find match and do something

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I am hoping I can get some guidance and help on python for loops. I have the following

my arrays look like this:

```
 arraysSortedByLargest = [('AWUF250816','AC','AMF01',192),
 ('CAPF3030B6', 'DB','ACL02',265),('CAPF3636A6','DB','ACL02',116)]



 arraysSortedByLargest2 = [('AWUF250816','AC',192),
     ('CAPF3030B6', 'DB',265)]



 #this is what I have done 



for largest1 in arraysSortedByLargest:

            for largest2 in arraysSortedByLargest2:

                if (largest1[0]==largest2[0] ):
                    #extend already used values to use later
                    modelsWithNoDJPMO.extend((largest1[0] , largest1[1]))
                    column = 1 
                    ws2.cell(row=row, column=column, value=largest1[0])
                    column += 1
                    ws2.cell(row=row, column=column, value=largest1[1])
                    column += 1
                    ws2.cell(row=row, column=column, value='0%')
                    row += 1 
                else:
                    # print 'here 2' + largest1[0] 
                    #do the same as if statement only change the last cell row value from '0%' to 'no value available'
                    #extend all the invalid values to use later in comparison
                    modelsWithNoOpportunities.extend((largest1[0] , largest1[1]))
```

Pretty much all I want to do is loop through both and compare tuple [0] to see if they match then i want to write it to my file if they dont I want to write it as well just with a different message.

I have struggled with this all day... I just cannot figure it out... I thought it should be as simple as two for loops the comparison and else statement but the else gives me all the iterations so I get every invalid test as opposed to only 1.

Then I decided to try the following:

push all the already "processed" records in one array and all the "invalid" records in another and in the end compare them and removed all the processed and that leaves me with only one unprocessed record which is close to what I need.

```
#print modelsWithNoOpportunities
            noOpp = list(set(modelsWithNoOpportunities) - set(modelsWithNoDJPMO))
```

`
The thing is... I think there has to be a better, easier, more efficient way to do this...

I have been reading a few different things and methods but I just dont get it.. here are some of the things i have tried:

```
        # while b < len( arraysSortedByLargest1):
        #     print largest1[0]
        #     # if arraysSortedByLargest[i][0]== arraysSortedByLargest1[b][0] ):  
        #     #     #print ' here if ' + ( arraysSortedByLargest1[b][0])
        #     # else:
        #         #print ' here else ' + ( arraysSortedByLargest1[b][0])
        #     b += 1
        # i += 1


        # for largest1, largest2  in zip arraysSortedByLargest,  arraysSortedByLargest1):
        #     print(largest1, largest2) 

        # for i, largest1 in enumerate arraysSortedByLargest):
        #     for largest2 in  arraysSortedByLargest1:   
        #         print  arraysSortedByLargest[i]
        #         print  arraysSortedByLargest1[i]

        # for largest1 in  arraysSortedByLargest:        
        #     modelsWithNoOpportunities=[];      
        #     for largest2 in  arraysSortedByLargest1:               
        #         #opportunity and production models match and DJPMO 0
        #         if(largest1[0]==largest2[0] and largest1[1]==largest2[1]):  
        #             modelsWithNoDJPMO.append(largest2[0] + ' ' + largest2[1])  
        #         else:
        #            modelsWithNoOpportunities.append(largest2[0]  + ' ' + largest2[1])
```

I am so confused at why the if statement works correctly and the else doesn't. The if statement returns all the matching records(without any duplicates or extra records). The else returns all the valid and invalid records(for the number of the outer and inner for loops).

Sorry I think I have come to a point where I have been looking at this for wayyyy too long and I am not even thinking logically anymore.

I don't want to lose so long stuck on this anymore... Any help will be greatly appreciated. I apologize if this is a very basic question, I have only been coding in python the last 3 days and this project needs to be completed in the next two days so I am against time.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Build a set to contain all first items in the item tuples in `arraysSortedByLargest`. Then loop through `arraysSortedByLargest2` checking if the first item in each tuple is in the set to write it to your files or else do the other thing

Comment: perfec this solved my problem!!! Thank you so much for pointing me on the right direction and being so exact with the process.

Answer (score 0):

as it was suggested in the comments I created a set containing the items in tuple i cared about and then looped through arraysortedbylargest2 and compared see below:

```
            s = set()

            for i in range(len(arraysSortedByLargest)):
                s.add(arraysSortedByLargest[i][0])

            for largest2 in arraysSortedByLargest2:
                if largest2[0] in s:
                    print 'here in if ' + largest2[0]
                    column = 1 
                    ws2.cell(row=row, column=column, value=largest2[0])
                    column += 1
                    ws2.cell(row=row, column=column, value=largest2[1])
                    column += 1
                    ws2.cell(row=row, column=column, value='0%')
                    row += 1 
                else:
                    print  'here in else ' +largest2[0]
                    column = 1 
                    ws2.cell(row=row, column=column, value=largest2[0])
                    column += 1
                    ws2.cell(row=row, column=column, value=largest2[1])
                    column += 1
                    ws2.cell(row=row, column=column, value='No opportunity data available')
                    row += 1
```